# Angular4 Implementing interfaces as Input

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but here goes.
In angular4, I'm creating an interface via the abstract class method ( https://hackernoon.com/creating-interfaces-for-angular-services-1bb41fbbe47c).

Making the abstract class is easy. I'm going to write all pseudocode here.

In one project, lets say Project A, I will have this interface:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class TestingService {
  abstract modifyString(): JsonObject;
}
```

In another project (project B), it takes in Project A as a dependency and stores it inside node_modules (using npm here). The main HTML page of project B does something like this:

```
<projectA (input1) (input2)... />
```

And here's the part I'm not sure if it's possible. In project B, I want to implement TestingService of project A. And then, when projectA is instantiated as shown above, it will run the implemented function from B. **Is it somehow possible to put the implemented function as Input into projectA?**

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm going to have other projects (C, D) that will also use A as a dependency. I want that modifyString() function to be different depending on which project uses it, while not hardcoding multiple implementations in project A itself.

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more details. Thanks!

Comment: you need to include the injectable service into one of the angular bootstrapeed application.

Comment: It's unclear what it should look like. Considering that Project A is an app, what is projectA, and if it's app root component, why does it accept inputs? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that could explain the idea would be helpful.